# How to store the variable value in bootstrap tag in meteor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, input, meteor, tags

How to store the variable value in bootstrap tag in 
meteor.

For example:

> input type="text" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing,Cairo" data-role="tagsinput"

http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already installed bootstrap:

```
meteor add twbs:bootstrap
```

Then you install the package which you have asked about:

```
meteor add ajduke:bootstrap-tagsinput
```

Then presumably in your template:

```
<template name="myFabTemplate">
    <section>
        <input type="text" value="{{getStuff}}" data-role="tagsinput">
    </section>
</template>
```

And in your template helper:

```
Template.myFabTemplate.helpers({
    getStuff: function(){
        return "Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing,Cairo";
    }
});
```

I've done a MeteorPad working example here:
http://meteorpad.com/pad/g4ArirBFKNdhbkbx5/tagsinput

Comment: Thanks for replying....actually I wanna store values in database from the client side. What will be the events to store in db.

Comment: My problem has been resolved.."click button": function(e, t) {

        for (j=1;j<=i;j++)
        {
            tag.insert({"uuid":y[j],"tag":$("input").val(),"time": Date.now()});

            //console.log(y[i]);
        }

    }